# Button that increase margin with React

Tags: css, reactjs, slider, card

I'm trying to create a card slider. Where if you click the next arrow button will increase the margin left that will show next card. Is there away that i can create a function that will increase a margin of an card slider when i click on it?

Example:
https://animedia.netlify.app/

Just like this person. When I inspect on this person card slider I found that when you press the next arrow it will increase the margin which will push to the next card. I wanna know if I can accomplish the same thing with react.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really looking for a carousel/swiper library. There are many availiable out there and you could search then on the npm.

Take a look at this one, https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper

it is pretty well maintained, and if you go on their site they basically have a lot of various exaples, including having multiple slides/cards and being able to navigate across them.